# Sub menus fallback to jqGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid

I am using `Asp.Net` `jqGRid` in one of my pages , no issues with that.However I have a drop down menu which is containing only few submenus at this stage , the issue I am having is that my submenus appear behind of the `jqGRid`.I dont know how do I solve this.I tried giving higher `z-index` to the div which wraps the menu , but no help.Here is the image

[image]
Any suggestions is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue got solved by setting the following styles to my div jgGridDiv which was containing the jqGrid .Here is my code

```
#jqGridDiv
{
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
```

It is working fine now.Also I set a higher z-index to my div which contained the menu , this is very important.

Comment: I just ran into this same issue doing IE8 testing with css menus and jqGrid. As freebird said, make sure you put a high z-index in the div that contains the menu. Even if the z-index of the ul/li elements are maxed out, it will still hide behind the grid. The div container is the key! (thanks guys, stackoverflow saved my arse again)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Developer Tools of Chrome to examine the "Computed Style" of the div where jqGrid are created.

I know two problems which can follow to effects which you describe:

- the usage of Compatibility Mode of IE. It's the problem which can exist only in Internet Explorer. Because of the problem I try to place in the `<head>` on every page which has jqGrid the line `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`. It works with all `!DOCTYPE` with exception HTML5 `!DOCTYPE` (`<!DOCTYPE html">`). More safe would be to set `"X-UA-Compatible"`

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge"/>
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

(like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc817572.aspx), but with another value of `"X-UA-Compatible"` HTTP header)

- `z-index` will be inherited from some parent div where you placed jqGrid. In the case you can consider to use place the `<table>` and the pager `<div>` inside of additional "container" div and set in the style of the div `position: relative; z-index: auto;` or `position: relative; z-index: 1;` (or other small value).

Comment: I have a div name jqGridDiv which is the container for jqGrid.So what should I do so that I can use z-index:auto , should I add another  div which will contain jqGridDiv

Comment: @freebird: To be able to set `z-index` the div `jqGridDiv` should have either absolute or relative position. So try to add `style="position: relative; z-index: auto;"` to the div `jqGridDiv`. If it will not help you can change `z-index: auto` to some another value like `z-index: 1`.

Comment: @freebird: Which browser you use for the tests? Do you use Chrome? Do you examined the `z-index` value of the menu and the `z-index` of jqGrid using Developer Tools? What are your results? There are only `z-index` which define which elements of the page can be over other. All situations which I know can be solved by `z-index`. If you have the test demo in Internet you can post the URL to me.

Comment: I tried this thing in chrome,opera and ff also.I will check the z-index properly of these components and let you know thanks.

Comment: thanks alot for your help , my issue got solved , I have posted my answer.Thanks